# How to drop an empty row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where there is one empty row every 10 rows, it looks like the following

```
    A    B    C    D    E
0
1   a    b    c    d    e
2   f    g    h    i    j
.....
```

I would like to drop the empty row in the dataframe, but the problem is the row is not filled with empty string `" "`, they are more like `""`.

Therefore, the `df.fillna` and `df.dropna` both do not work and I'm not sure how to replace them.

Any suggestion would be helpful! Thank you guys!

Comment: Replace space by `NaN` and then use `dropna`

Comment: Empty string is `""`...`" "` is a string with space. `bool("")-->False`, `bool(" ")-->True`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter all rows with no empty values like:

```
df = df[df.ne('').all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's every 10 rows as you say you may do something like:

```
df_clean = df[df.index % 10 != 0]
```

Which will drop every 10th row starting at the first one.